# Changing a Label when a Bool variable turns True

Tags: c#, wpf, events, delegates, event-handling

I'm not really sure how to explain this... I'm going to put the code in psuedo code for easy reading.

Pretty much I want a label to change its text when a bool variable of a class changes... I'm not sure what I need to use since I'm using WPF and the class can't just change the label I don't think?

Do i need some sort of event?  Or a WPF event?  Thanks for any help.

```
public MainWindow()
{
   SomeClass temp = new SomeClass();

   void ButtonClick(sender, EventArgs e)
   {  
      if (temp.Authenticate)
        label.Content = "AUTHENTICATED";
   }
}

public SomeClass
{
  bool _authenticated;

  public bool Authenticate()
  {
    //send UDP msg
    //wait for UDP msg for authentication
    //return true or false accordingly
  }
}
```

Comment: I would do this with data triggers in Xaml, avoiding any code-behind at all...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another WPF approach other than BradleyDotNet's answer is to use triggers. This will be purely XAML based without converter code.

**XAML:**

```
<Label>
  <Label.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsAuthenticated}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Content" Value="Authenticated" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

Same rule applies as mentioned by BradledDotNet, ViewModel should be attached and "IsAuthenticated" property should raise the PropertyChanged event.

-- Add some boilerplate code as suggested by Gayot Fow --

**View Code Behind:**

For simplicity I will just set the DataContext of the view in code behind. For a better design you can use ViewModelLocator as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462040/what-is-a-viewmodellocator-and-what-are-its-pros-cons-compared-to-datatemplates).

```
public partial class SampleWindow : Window
{
  SampleModel _model = new SampleModel();

  public SampleWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = _model; // attach the model/viewmodel to DataContext for binding in XAML
  }
}
```

**Example Model** (it should really be ViewModel):

The main point here is the attached model/viewmodel has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class SampleModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  bool _isAuthenticated = false;

  public bool IsAuthenticated {
    get { return _isAuthenticated; }
    set {
      if (_isAuthenticated != value) {
        _isAuthenticated = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsAuthenticated"); // raising this event is key to have binding working properly
      }
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  void OnPropertyChanged(string propName) {
    if (PropertyChanged != null) {
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While other answers will work, this approach is a lot more scalable and less code-intensive, hence the "preferred" approach.  A single line of Xaml can simultaneously change the background colour to green on the same binding source for example.  @techhero, I would suggest amending your answer to include the requisite boiler plate for the INPC because the OP is new to WPF, as well as future consumers of this question.

Comment: something at work came up but promise to review everyone's answer here  when my time frees up later today or tomorrow...as my main goal is to learn.. so i really thank everyone for their time

Answer (score 4):

Since we are using WPF, I would use a binding and converter to accomplish this:

```
<Page.Resources>
   <local:BoolToAuthenticationStringConverter x:Key="BoolToAuthenticationStringConverter"/>
</Page>

<Label Content="{Binding Path=IsAuthenticated, Converter={StaticResource BoolToAuthenticationStringConverter}"/>
```

Then a converter that looks like:

```
public class BoolToAuthenticationStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert (...)
   {
      if ((bool)value)
         return "Authenticated!";
      else
         return "Not Authenticated!";
   }

   public object ConvertBack (...)
   {
      //We don't care about this one for this converter
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

In our XAML, we declare the converter in the resources section, then use it as the "Converter" option of the binding for "Content". In the code, we cast `value` to a bool (`IsAuthenticated` is assumed to be a bool in your ViewModel), and return an appropriate string. Make sure your ViewModel implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and that `IsAuthenticated` raises the `PropertyChanged` event for this to work!

**Note:** Since you won't be changing the `Label` via the UI, you don't need to worry about `ConvertBack`. You could set the mode to `OneWay` to make sure that it never gets called though.

Granted, this is very specific to this scenario. We could make a generic one:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=IsAuthenticated, Converter={StaticResource BoolDecisionToStringConverter}, ConverterParameter='Authenticated;Not Authenticated'}"/>
```

Then a converter that looks like:

```
public class BoolDecisionToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert (...)
   {
      string[] args = String.Split((String)parameter, ';');
      if ((bool)value)
         return args[0];
      else
         return args[1];
   }

   public object ConvertBack (...)
   {
      //We don't care about this one for this converter
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

Comment: This looks a lot more WPF-y. Thanks for elaborating on it!

Comment: something came up but promise i'll still look at yours and Jeroen's answer!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need an event.

Consider a sample like this:

```
public SomeClass {
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> AuthenticateEvent;  
    boolean isAuthenticated;

    public bool Authenticate()
    {
        // Do things
        isAuthenticated = true;
        AuthenticateEvent(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}

public MainWindow()
{
   SomeClass temp = new SomeClass();

   public MainWindow(){
      temp.AuthenticateEvent+= OnAuthentication;
      temp.Authenticate();
   }

   private void OnAuthentication(object sender, EventArgs e){
       Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
           label.Content = "AUTHENTICATED";
       }); 
   }
}
```

Now whenever `temp` fires the `Authenticate` event, it will change your label.

Comment: kk will read right now and get back to you, thank you very much

Comment: even better would be binding with a converter, but this will technically work.

Comment: `Yes, you need an event.1` I wouldn't say that so sure. I could implement it with async/await without any event.

Comment: i'd be interested in seeing it for knowledge purposes @L.B. if you were interested in showing.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: if there is a more common way in WPF to do this, feel free to add it as an answer. I have limited experience with WPF so I'm approaching this from a general C# perspective.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, Ok, thanks for the response! I posted a "WPF" way of doing it.