# Correct way to data-bind collections to ComboBox in WPF using MVVM?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm using **MVVM** pattern, developing my **WPF** application. I also use *Entity Framework* as ORM. Here're my models (**EF**):

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int OfficeId { get; set; }
    public Office Office { get; set; }
}

public class Office : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class Department : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Office> Offices { get; set; }
}
```

Let's assume, that I've got an instance of `User` class from my context:

```
   var userInstance = context.Get<User>().Single(user => user.ID == 1);
```

Now I'd like to pass this instance to my View to make some changes for concrete user (called, for example, `UserEditView`), so I have to create a `UserModel` class to deal with `User` data according to MVVM. So, here's what I think I have to write in my code:

```
public class UserModel : ObservableObject
{
    private User user;

    public string Office Office
    {
        get
        {
            return this.user.Office.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            //what shoud I write Here??
            if(value != user.Office)
            {
                 user.Office=value;
                 OnPropertyChanged("Office");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm really frustrated! How should I deal with that? There're thousands of examples, but they are so simple. I'm wondering what should I do to have a ComboBox in my EditView with a list of all Offices, existing in my DB. And list of Offices should depend on another one Combobox, which contains a list of Departments.

- But where should I get this lists from?
- Should I pass a collection from my UserModel? Or what?
- Can anybody give me a simple example about how to do this correctly?

*PS*: Of course, I know couple ways to implement such behaviour, but in that case my code seems to be ugly and  not maintainable. Please, help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One thing you are missing is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged for each object you want to bind the XAML too. Start here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-does-a-better-way-exist

Comment: @Kenny, I know about INPC, of course. But that's not the point..

Comment: Typically for me, I would use IOC to inject in your data store(s) into the constructor. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25524753/3225

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is depends on your DB architecture. Here is some common suggestion (but there can be a lot of others).

1. Don't panic - you have a correct question.
2. Create the view model set it to be a main view model of your window.
3. In your view model create **two collections** Users (containing UserModels) and Departments (containing DepartmentMode), **since you want to change offices each time you re-select department, you don't need the Offices collection in main view model**.
4. Pull each collection data from your data base.
5. Implement each model with INPC.
6. Take in account the WPF MVVM best practices.
7. Apply a correct bindings.
8. And be happy - you are a programmer.

**Updates - 1**

**XAML code**

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <someBindingExampleSoHelpAttempt:MainViewModel/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="someBindingExampleSoHelpAttempt:UserModel">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Text="{Binding LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                <ComboBox Grid.Column="2"
                                          IsTextSearchEnabled="True"     
                                          IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False"     
                                          StaysOpenOnEdit="True"    
                                          TextSearch.TextPath="DepartmentName"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                    AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.Departments}"    
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding Department}"     
                                          DisplayMemberPath="DepartmentName" 
                                          IsEditable="True"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"     
                                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                <ComboBox Grid.Column="3"
                                          IsTextSearchEnabled="True"     
                                          IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False"     
                                          StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
                                          IsEditable="True"
                                          TextSearch.TextPath="OfficeName"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding OfficesCollection}"    
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding Office}"     
                                          DisplayMemberPath="OfficeName"      
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"     
                                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            </Grid>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView></Grid>
```

**VM and models**

```
    public class MainViewModel:BaseObservableObject
{
    private DepartmentModel _selectedDepartment;
    private OfficeModel _selectedOffice;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Dal = new DataLayer();
        Users = new ObservableCollection<UserModel>();
        Departments = new ObservableCollection<DepartmentModel>(Dal.GetAllDepartments());
        InitUsersCollection();
    }

    private void InitUsersCollection()
    {
        if(Departments == null) return;
        Departments.ToList().ForEach(model =>
        {
            model.Offices.ToList().ForEach(officeModel =>
            {
                if (officeModel.Users == null) return;
                officeModel.Users.ToList().ForEach(userModel => Users.Add(userModel));
            });
        });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<UserModel> Users { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<DepartmentModel> Departments { get; set; }

    private DataLayer Dal { get; set; }

}

public class DataLayer
{
    public List<DepartmentModel> GetAllDepartments()
    {
        //pull and map your using your DB service
        //For example:
        return new List<DepartmentModel>
        {
            new DepartmentModel
            {
                DepartmentId = 1,
                DepartmentName = "A",
                Offices = new ObservableCollection<OfficeModel>
                {
                    new OfficeModel
                    {
                        DepartmentId = 1,
                        OfficeName = "AA",
                        Users = new ObservableCollection<UserModel>(new List<UserModel>
                        {
                            new UserModel {Name = "Avicenna", LastName = "Abu Ali Abdulloh Ibn-Sino"},
                            new UserModel {Name = "Omar", LastName = "Khayyam"},
                            new UserModel {Name = "RAMBAM", LastName = "Moshe ben Maimon"}
                        })
                    },
                    new OfficeModel 
                    {

                        DepartmentId = 1, 
                        OfficeName = "AB", 
                        Users = new ObservableCollection<UserModel>(new List<UserModel>
                        {
                            new UserModel {Name = "Leo", LastName = "Tolstoi"},
                            new UserModel {Name = "Anton", LastName = "Chekhov"},
                        })},
                }
            },
            new DepartmentModel
            {
                DepartmentId = 2,
                DepartmentName = "B",
                Offices = new ObservableCollection<OfficeModel>
                {
                    new OfficeModel
                    {
                        DepartmentId = 2, OfficeName = "BA",
                        Users = new ObservableCollection<UserModel>(new List<UserModel>
                        {
                            new UserModel {Name = "B", LastName = "O"},
                            new UserModel {Name = "B", LastName = "N"},
                        }),
                    },
                    new OfficeModel
                    {
                        DepartmentId = 2, OfficeName = "BB",
                        Users = new ObservableCollection<UserModel>(new List<UserModel>
                        {
                            new UserModel {Name = "John", LastName = "Walker"},
                            new UserModel {Name = "Gregory", LastName = "Rasputin"},
                        }),
                    },
                }
            },
            new DepartmentModel
            {
                DepartmentId = 3,
                DepartmentName = "C",
                Offices = new ObservableCollection<OfficeModel>
                {
                    new OfficeModel {DepartmentId = 3, OfficeName = "CA"},
                    new OfficeModel {DepartmentId = 3, OfficeName = "CB"},
                    new OfficeModel {DepartmentId = 3, OfficeName = "CC"}
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

public class OfficeModel:BaseObservableObject
{
    private int _departmentModel;
    private string _officeName;
    private DepartmentModel _department;
    private ObservableCollection<UserModel> _users;

    public int DepartmentId
    {
        get { return _departmentModel; }
        set
        {
            _departmentModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DepartmentModel Department
    {
        get { return _department; }
        set
        {
            _department = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string OfficeName
    {
        get { return _officeName; }
        set
        {
            _officeName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<UserModel> Users
    {
        get { return _users; }
        set
        {
            _users = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(()=>Users);
        }
    }
}

public class DepartmentModel:BaseObservableObject
{

    private string _departmentName;

    public string DepartmentName
    {
        get { return _departmentName; }
        set
        {
            _departmentName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<OfficeModel> Offices { get; set; }
}

public class UserModel:BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _name;
    private string _lastName;
    private DepartmentModel _department;
    private OfficeModel _office;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {
            _lastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DepartmentModel Department
    {
        get { return _department; }
        set
        {
            _department = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(()=>OfficesCollection);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<OfficeModel> OfficesCollection
    {
        get { return Department.Offices; }
    }

    public OfficeModel Office
    {
        get { return _office; }
        set
        {
            _office = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// implements the INotifyPropertyChanged (.net 4.5)
/// </summary>
public class BaseObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> raiser)
    {
        var propName = ((MemberExpression)raiser.Body).Member.Name;
        OnPropertyChanged(propName);
    }

    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(name);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**But please take in account that this is only one of hundreds ways to do that.**
The SO here if you will need the code example.
Regards.

Comment: It would be great if you give a little example

Comment: @klutch1991 with pleasure just give me a couple of minutes :)