# Conditional ViewModel binding to single View in MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, ninject

I've recently read few articles about using IoC in MVVM application. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25524753/4945059) great answer for example. And I started thinking, what If I have single View and four ViewModels. I don't know which one should be attached to the View's DataContext at the design time. I will know that during runtime.

Like, in that answer I have locator:

```
class IocConfiguration : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IStorage>().To<Storage>().InSingletonScope();

        Bind<UserControlViewModel>().ToSelf().InTransientScope().WithConstructorArguments( ... ).Named("UserControlViewModelA");
        Bind<UserControlViewModel>().ToSelf().InTransientScope().WithConstructorArguments( ... ).Named("UserControlViewModelB");
        Bind<UserControlViewModel>().ToSelf().InTransientScope().WithConstructorArguments( ... ).Named("UserControlViewModelC");
        Bind<UserControlViewModel>().ToSelf().InTransientScope().WithConstructorArguments( ... ).Named("UserControlViewModelD");

    }
}

class ViewModelLocator
{
    public UserControlViewModel UserControlViewModelA
    {
        get { return IocKernel.Get<UserControlViewModel>("UserControlViewModelA"); }
    }

    public UserControlViewModel UserControlViewModelB
    {
        get { return IocKernel.Get<UserControlViewModel>("UserControlViewModelB"); }
    }

    public UserControlViewModel UserControlViewModelC
    {
        get { return IocKernel.Get<UserControlViewModel>("UserControlViewModelC"); }
    }

    public UserControlViewModel UserControlViewModelD
    {
        get { return IocKernel.Get<UserControlViewModel>("UserControlViewModelD"); }
    }        
}
```

**My question is. How should I handle it in my View?** which is:

```
<UserControl 
    ...
    DataContext="{Binding UserControlViewModelA, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">

    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

What I mean is, I am struggling with assigning different ViewModel at runtime. Design time is not a problem. The problem is what approach should I take to set particular ViewModel to this view at runtime and keep best programming practices alive

Comment: What MVVM framework are you using?

Comment: @RossDargan None. Basically you don't need any framework to use solution from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25524753/5883596

Comment: @RossDargan Are you suggesting to use specific one? I'm gonna use MVVM Light, but still don't know how to solve my problem :/