# Make sure that one static class is created before the other

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, static-classes

I am developing a C#/WPF/MVVM/UWP app which uses a ViewModelLocator which looks like this:

```
    public class ViewModelLocator
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
        "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
        Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
    public MainPageViewModel MainPage
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainPageViewModel>();
        }
    }


    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        // DEBUG LINE: var test = Views.ViewLocator.MainPageKey;
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, Design.DesignDataService>();
        }
        else
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
        }

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainPageViewModel>();
    }
}
```

I have another class, a ViewLocator, for navigation purposes which looks like this:

```
    public class ViewLocator
{
    public static readonly string MainPageKey = typeof(MainPage).Name;
    public static readonly string WorkPageKey = typeof(WorkPage).Name;

    static ViewLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        var navigationService = new NavigationService();

        navigationService.Configure(MainPageKey, typeof(MainPage));
        navigationService.Configure(WorkPageKey, typeof(WorkPage));

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService>(() => navigationService);

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDialogService, DialogService>();
    }
}
```

Before, both classes were combined in ViewModelLocator, however i figured that the ViewModelLocator as part of the "ViewModels-Side-of-things" should be unaware of the views and it's types, which is why I refactored that code into two classes.

My MainPageView then has a button, which triggers a navigation command in the MainPageView.cs

```
    public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private INavigationService _navigationService;

    public RelayCommand CreateNewImageCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;

        CreateNewImageCommand = new RelayCommand(CreateNewImage, () => true);
    }

    public void CreateNewImage()
    {
        _navigationService.NavigateTo(Views.ViewLocator.WorkPageKey);
    }
}
```

For completeness, here is my App.xaml

```
<Application
...>

<Application.Resources>
    <v:ViewLocator x:Key="ViewLocator" />
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Now what happens is this: if I don't have the DEBUG LINE in ViewModelLocator, at the point at which MainPage requests its ViewModel from the ViewModelLocator, the constructor of ViewLocator has not been called yet and `return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainPageViewModel>();` throws an exception. If I include the DEBUG LINE, this forces the ViewLocator Constructor to be run first, and everything works fine.

How can I achieve this behaviour without that odd debug line?

Comment: I'm just going to leave this here [Is ServiceLocator anti-pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795459/is-servicelocator-anti-pattern)

Comment: TL;DR You should really be using Dependency Injection not service locator pattern. Typically if starting from scratch it's a much better and easier pattern to understand.

Comment: @Liam I'm not a fan of IoC Containers or ServiceLocator or whatever you want to call it. It's just that I have been researching how to properly separate VM and V and this is the only working approach that satisfies me so far. I'm however very open to using DI - if you could please show me some reference code that employs it properly.

Comment: Most people use an [IoC framework these days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288/which-net-dependency-injection-frameworks-are-worth-looking-into). For example [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/)

Comment: Have a look at Caliburn Micro; it will do the heavy lifting for you and you get IoC... yes, IoC is the way to go.

Comment: I have been using MVVM Light and its SimpleIoC so far. I feel what you are saying is I should eliminate the ViewModelLocator. Reading about IoC and DI is all fine but I don't seem to be capable of figuring out how to use this with MVVM. Examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into the reason most developers do not use static classes and a service locator.

As suggested in your comments try using dependency injection. This allows inversion of control for the component that manages this wiring.

Look into MEF or Unity as a framework to use rather than rolling your own IoC. Both have advantages and disadvantages but either will work. They also allow for easier and cleaner testing.

[MEF](https://mef.codeplex.com/)

[Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Despite of all the comments and other answers, I think that I was on the track after all. To solve or rather bypass this problem, I have created added bootstrapping of the SimpleIoC Container in the Startup of the App and move the code from the `ViewLocator`'s constructor there.

I also removed the ServiceLocator calls, which was sort of redundant and rely on `SimpleIoC.Default` now directly.

The Navigator is still injected into the ViewModels by the `SimpleIoC` Container. The ViewModelLocator however is necessary work in conjuction with the XAML code.

I recommend this answer as a starting point for others who are also struggling with this issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25524753/2175012

After all, I have taken the side that ServiceLocators are no anti pattern but have to be used carefully.