# Why my Subscribe method is not called when using Prism EventAggregator?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, autofac

I am learning Prism. Few hours already I am facing a problem, when subscribing to the event, the subscription method is not called. I am using **Prism** and **Autofac**.

In the simplified example below, in **MainViewModel** `Publish("dupa");` event is called in the `ctor`. And on button click **UpdateWindow** is opened. In backend of the window is created instance of **UpdateViewModel**.

Inside of **update VM** `ctor` is ran, but after `Subscribe(UpdateName);` the **UpdateName** is not executed, because of some reason that I do not understand.

Complete code:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
        public MainViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            _eventAggregator = eventAggregator; //Prism

            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<UpdateNameEvent>().Publish("dupa");

            OnOpenCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnOpenWin);
        }

        public void OnOpenWin(object obj)
        {
            UpdateWindow win = new UpdateWindow();
            win.Show();
        }

        public ICommand OnOpenCommand { get; private set; }
    }


public class UpdateViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

        public UpdateViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            _eventAggregator = eventAggregator; //Prism
            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<UpdateNameEvent>().Subscribe(UpdateName);
        }

        private void UpdateName(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name; //is not called at all
        }

        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }


public partial class UpdateWindow : Window
    {
        public UpdateWindow()
        {
            var bootStrapper = new BootStrapper();
            var container = bootStrapper.BootStrap();
            UpdateViewModel vm = container.Resolve<UpdateViewModel>();
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = vm;
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

After investigating, I notied, that when subscribing to the events like this, it works fine:

`Utility.EventAggregator.GetEvent<UpdateNameEvent>().Subscribe(UpdateName);`

When subscribing with used injected **eventAggregator**, it does not work:

`_eventAggregator.GetEvent<UpdateNameEvent>().Subscribe(UpdateName);`

And **EventAggregator** is registered by **Autofac** as follows:

```
builder.RegisterType<EventAggregator>()
        .As<IEventAggregator>().SingleInstance();
```

I do not understand why this dependency does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not understand why this dependency does not work?

Because you create a new `EventAggregator` for the `UpdateViewModel`.

```
var bootStrapper = new BootStrapper();
var container = bootStrapper.BootStrap();
UpdateViewModel vm = container.Resolve<UpdateViewModel>();
```

This looks as if a new container is created for the `UpdateWindow`, and the new container will have a new - that is, a different - `EventAggregator`. Those two will not send events to each other, of course.

So the solution is to use one single container to resolve all your stuff. This is what happens when you use the static `Utility`. You should avoid using a service-locator like this. Have a look at the `ViewModelLocator`, which makes it really easy to create the view models for a given view, for example, or pass the container to the `UpdateWindow` when it is created (somewhat ugly, too, though).

Comment: It sounds interesting. As I am using Prism, Ill try to use its automatic VM locator...

Comment: Based on this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366291/how-to-handle-dependency-injection-in-a-wpf-mvvm-application I created VM locator and resolved EventAggregator as a singletone and it worked. Thank you