# Why my Autofac registered Prism EventAggregator is not injected properly into viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, autofac

In my solution I am using **Autofac**, and **Prism** as well. Below is a simplified project that explains what happens.

I am registering my views, view models and `EventAggregator` in **Autofac**'s container class like that:

```
public class BootStrapper
        {
            public IContainer BootStrap()
            {
                var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

                builder.RegisterType<EventAggregator>()
            .As<IEventAggregator>().SingleInstance();

                builder.RegisterType<MainWindow>().AsSelf();
                builder.RegisterType<ChildView1>().AsSelf();
                builder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>().AsSelf();
                builder.RegisterType<Child1ViewModel>().AsSelf();

                return builder.Build();
            }
        }
```

Note, that when registering view models as a singletons, effect was the same. I am injecting `EventAggregator` into my VM like that:

```
public class MainViewModel
    {
        private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
        public MainViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

            UpdateName("Name1");
        }

        public void UpdateName(string name)
        {

            ChildView1 win1 = new ChildView1(); //in the backend Child1ViewModel is assigend to its DataContext
            win1.Show();

            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<UpdateNameEvent>().Publish(name); //this does not work
        }
    }
```

Code above does not work. Because of some reason (*I hope that you will tell me why*), when executing `UpdateName` method, this dependency does not work, and inside of **Child1ViewModel** class `UpdateName` method is not executed:

```
public class Child1ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

        public Child1ViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<UpdateNameEvent>().Subscribe(UpdateName);
        }

        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateName(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name; //debug does not hit this code line
        }
    }
```

Constructor of **Child1ViewModel** is hiten during debug, just `UpdateName` is not executed. BUT, if I use direct call of the `EventAggregator`, like this:

`Utility.EventAggregator.GetEvent<UpdateNameEvent>().Subscribe(UpdateName);`

or this:

`Utility.EventAggregator.GetEvent<UpdateNameEvent>().Publish(name);`

it works! When assuming, that Utility class looks like:

```
public class Utility
    {
        public static EventAggregator EventAggregator { get; set; }

        static Utility()
        {
            EventAggregator = new EventAggregator();
        }
    }
```

I suspect, that there is some problem with registering the aggregator in **Autofac**, but I have no idea what is the problem, I just used it as per odl exaples I found.

Resolving **Child1ViewModel** and **MainViewModel**:

```
public partial class ChildView1 : Window
    {
        public ChildView1()
        {
            var bootStrapper = new BootStrapper();
            var container = bootStrapper.BootStrap();
            Child1ViewModel vm = container.Resolve<Child1ViewModel>();
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = vm;
        }
    }

public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            var bootStrapper = new BootStrapper();
            var container = bootStrapper.BootStrap();
            MainViewModel vm = container.Resolve<MainViewModel>();
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = vm;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Prism's ViewModelLocator mechanism. My assumption is based on that you are manually instantiating *ChildView1* rather than resolving it with dependency injection container and state in the comment that viewModel is resolved in the background.

You must change the container of Prism ViewModelLocator used for resolving the ViewModel instances as shown below.

```cs
ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewModelFactory(viewModelType) =>
{
    return YourAutofacContainer.Resolve<viewModelType>();
});
```

For further information see [Control how ViewModels are Resolved](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/viewmodel-locator.html#control-how-viewmodels-are-resolved).

Keep in mind that for keeping single instance lifetime scope of object instances consistent throughout your whole application, you must use the same dependency injection container instance for resolving objects and this objects' parent objects all the way up to the root object.

Comment: I use Autofac IoC, and each VM is resolved in each view backend, to assign DataContext

Comment: Can you show the code where you resolve MainViewModel and Child1ViewModel? Btw if Utility class is actually a part of your application instead of an example to prove your point, you must use ioc to resolve event aggregator at that point too.

Comment: Just updated the question with resolving both VM

Comment: Now we can see your problem clearly and my suspicion was on point as I stated in the last paragraph of my answer. You are creating two different instances of dependency injection container and expect to get a single instance of event aggregator. Just move your container creation to your application's composition root and use this single instance of dependency injection container throughout your whole application.

Comment: You suggest, that I am supposed to resolve both VM in `App.xaml.cs`?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that. I'm suggesting that you use one single container.

Comment: Ok, Ill try to work now on using ViewModelLocator to resolve all Views and VMs in one place, searching for some solution right now, but I belive you are right, I will come back to this shortly...

Comment: Based on this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366291/how-to-handle-dependency-injection-in-a-wpf-mvvm-application I created VM locator and resolved EventAggregator as a singletone and it worked. Thank you