# ViewModels with MVVLight

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am new in MVVM Light. I try to write a project with MVVM Light Framework and I have some questions. I have defined my MainWindow.xaml like this:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Height="30" Width="40" Command="{Binding OpenNews}">News</Button>
        <Button Height="30" Width="40" Margin="5,0,0,0" Command="{Binding OpenTeams}">Teams</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <ContentPresenter  Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
</Grid>
```

MainViewModel:
Contains the two `RelayCommands` OpenNews and OpenTeams. And also the CurrentViewModel property. This property contains the ViewModel depending on the option which the user clicks (NewsViewModel or TeamsViewModel).I do that like this:

```
    private void ShowOpenTeams()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<TeamsViewModel>(); //MainViewModel.TeamsViewModel;
    }

    private void ShowOpenNews()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<NewsViewModel>();
    }
```

app.xaml:
I have defined the relation between ViewModel's DataType and the View that should be shown.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:NewsViewModel}">
        <view:NewsView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TeamsViewModel}">
        <view:TeamView/>
    </DataTemplate>        
    <!--Global View Model Locator-->
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"
                         d:IsDataSource="True" />
</Application.Resources>
```

The question is: why do I need the ViewModelLocator in this case? Does using ViewModelLocator make sense with this approach? I don't see any benefit...

The Views in MVVM Light are created with this relation `DataContext="{Binding ViewModelName, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"` but I wonder which approach is it usefull with?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462040/what-is-a-viewmodellocator-and-what-are-its-pros-cons-compared-to-datatemplates

Comment: The ViewModelLocator is his implementation of an inversion of control container for dependency injection, I usually switch it out for Castle.Windsor and do all my di in app.xaml.cs.

Comment: @reggaeguitar Do you know any sample to see in action the ViewModelLocator? It seems,I don't need ViewModelLocator With DataTemplates...

Comment: Here I instanciate first the ViewModel. I set every time the right ViewModel in the property CurrentViewModel and the data is shown through the defined DataTemplates. How can I instanciate View and pass as parameter the right ViewModel? I guess the IoC Container creates the view and pass the view model parameter