# How to bind two different class properties in DataTemplate

Tags: data-binding, uwp, binding, datatemplate, winui-3

I am trying to bind two properties from different classes in DataTemplate.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DemoItemTemplate" x:DataType="local:DemoInfo">
   <NavigationViewItem Visibility="{Binding Visibility, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{x:Bind Name}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

`DataType` set as `DemoInfo` for this `DataTemplate` and `Name` value updated from `DemoInfo`.

I have tried view model as source and relative source binding. But `Visibility` property binding not working from `ViewModel` class. Any suggest how to achieve this?

```
Visibility="{Binding Visibility, Source={StaticResource viewModel}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK , you cant use multibinding in UWP , you can try to use Locator [What is a ViewModelLocator and what are its pros/cons compared to DataTemplates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462040/what-is-a-viewmodellocator-and-what-are-its-pros-cons-compared-to-datatemplates)

Answer (score 0):

> How to bind two different class properties in DataTemplate

If you bind Visibility with `StaticResource`, please declare ViewModel class in your page `Resources` like the following.

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Visibility = false;
    }
    public bool Visibility { get; set; }
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
</Page.Resources>


<DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
        <TextBlock
            Width="100"
            Height="44"
            Text="{x:Bind Name}"
            Visibility="{Binding Visibility, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

**Update**

If you want Visibility value changed dynamically at run-time, you need implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface for ViewModel class.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Visibility = false;
    }
    private bool _visibility;
    public bool Visibility
    {
        get
        {

            return _visibility;
        }

        set
        {
            _visibility = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
}
```

For more detail please refer [Data binding in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) official document.

Comment: Thanks, but it working fine when application loaded and not working when the Visibility value changed dynamically at run-time. I have set mode as TwoWay and UpdateSourceTrigger as PropertyChanged in xaml and RaisePropertyChanged() used for Visibility property in ViewModel class.

Comment: You need implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for ViewModel class

Comment: @KanniyappanP, I have updated the case reply, please check.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I thought the `Visibility` property had a dedicated enum that contains all the possible options ([Visibility Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.visibility?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)) for the `Visibility` property.  So, your binding might be working just fine, but the `Type` of the bound property would need to be of type `Visibility` using `System.Windows`.

On a side note, I wouldn't put a visibility property in the view model anyway.  I think a more standard approach would be to have a visibility `DependencyProperty` in the immediate code behind of the view for your binding.