# How can I access the value of a field in ViewModelA from another ViewModel that is called by ViewModelA

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a page and a popup page.

```
public partial class PageA
{
    public PageAViewModel vm;

    public PageA()
    {
        BindingContext = vm = new PageAViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

public partial class PageAViewModel
{
    public int Field1;
    public int Field2;
    public int Field3;

    public async Task OpenPopup()
    {
        PopupA popup = new PopupA();
        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(popup);
    }

    public void Method1() { }:
```

And

```
public partial class PopupA
{
    public PopupViewModel vm;

    public PopupA()
    {
        BindingContext = vm = new PopupViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

public partial class PopupViewModel
{
    // How can I get the value of Field1, Field2 and Field3 here? 
    // How can I call Method1 here?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass a reference to the VM when creating the popup

```
PopupA popup = new PopupA(this);
```

then in PopupA

```
public PopupA(PageAViewModel vma)
{
    BindingContext = vm = new PopupViewModel(vma);
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

then in PopupViewModel

```
public PopupViewModel(PageAViewModel vma)
{
    // now this VM has a reference to PageAViewModel
}
```

note that this is not a great design approach and it is deeply coupling these two classes

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more.  What I am trying to do is to give PopupViewModel a reference to the PageAViewmodel's fields and methods.

Comment: I agree with your comments about the coupling.  Do you have any suggestion on how this could be solved?

Comment: Can you please check this line.  I believe you mean I should pass a reference to the ViewModel but here you suggest passing a page reference.

Comment: if the code **you** posted the line `PopupA popup = new PopupA();` is contained in `PageAViewModel`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding a design pattern in your project . I use MVVM Light and in that I add a `ViewModelLocator` class to create a singleton pattern.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-mvvm-viewmodel-locator-using-mvvm-light/

Following the link and then you can write

```
var xyz = App.ViewModelLocator.YourViewModel.YourPublicProperty;
```

Comment: Are you using MVVM Light for every ViewModel in your project.  How about the simple case where BindingContext = vm = new PageAViewModel(); works.  Is there any advantage in using MVVM light for this?

Comment: the advantage is your code management there is no coding ethic violation in using singleton pattern as opposed to the other answer which is sort of a fix rather than a solution which is scalable, modular and robust.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462040/what-is-a-viewmodellocator-and-what-are-its-pros-cons-compared-to-datatemplates